# typeorm saving list as string

Tags: arrays, postgresql, typeorm

I have a flutter frontend which sends url strings in a list like ['url','url','url'] but in Postgres its saved/on retrieval shows up as a single string like 'url,url,url'.

Here's the column with problem:

```
  @Column({
    type: "simple-array",
    default: [],
  })
  postMedia!: string[];
```

Here's the repository method that saves the post:

```
  async addPost(req: Request, res: Response) {
    let { email } = req.params;
    let postText = req.body.postText;
    let postMedia: string[] = req.body.postMedia;

    let accountRepo = getCustomRepository(AccountRepository);
    let account = await accountRepo.findOne({
      email: email,
    });

    try {
      let post = new PostEntity();
      post.postText = postText;
      post.postMedia = postMedia;
      post.account = account!;
      await post.save();

      return res.send({
        message: "Post Added",
        added: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.send({
        message: "Something went wrong",
        added: false,
      });
    }
  }
```

Where is the problem? Why isn't the list saved as array even after I typed the postMedia variable as `string[]`? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
@Column("text", { array: true })
postMedia!: string[];
```

Do let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: It worked. thank you so much. I just had to add `nullable: true` to fit my case.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work for me. It tells me `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'array NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 1`

Comment: This answer is related to postgres database and you are using mysql